# Dagger and Kotlin - Issue with binding a class to its generic supertype

Tags: kotlin, dagger-2, dagger

I'm banging my head against the wall right now because I can't figure this out.
I have a generic Interface called `Mapper` which has two generic type parameters. Now I want to leverage multibinding and bind multiple implementations of this interface into a map of type `Map<Class<out Any>, Provider<Mapper<Any, Any>>`. My code looks as follows:

```
interface Mapper<DTO, Entity> {
    
    fun toEntity(model: DTO): Entity
    
    fun toDto(model: Entity): DTO
    
}


class PersistedIntakeEntryMapper @Inject constructor() : Mapper<PersistedIntakeEntry, IntakeEntry> {

    override fun toEntity(model: PersistedIntakeEntry): IntakeEntry { TODO() }

    override fun toDto(model: IntakeEntry): PersistedIntakeEntry { TODO() }

}

@Module
interface MapperModule {

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @MapperKey(PersistedIntakeEntry::class)
    @ModelMappers
    fun bindPersistedIntakeEntryMapper(mapper: PersistedIntakeEntryMapper): Mapper<Any, Any>

}

@Singleton
class MapperFactory @Inject constructor(
    @ModelMappers val mappers: Map<Class<out Any>, @JvmSuppressWildcards Provider<Mapper<Any, Any>>>,
) {

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    inline fun <reified DTO: Any, Entity> get(): Mapper<DTO, Entity>? {
        TODO()
    }

}
```

Dagger is specifically complaining that `PersistedIntakeEntryMapper` is not assignable to `Mapper<Any, Any>`: `MapperModule.java:13: error: @Binds methods' parameter type must be assignable to the return type`.
However: the curious thing is that I have the same setup for another component which works like a charm:

```
interface ViewModelFactory<VM : ViewModel, SavedState, Parameters> {

   fun create(savedState: SavedState?, parameters: Parameters?): VM

}


class SetCalorieGoalViewModelFactory @Inject constructor(
    private val getCalorieGoalUseCase: GetCalorieGoalUseCase,
    private val setCalorieGoalUseCase: SetCalorieGoalUseCase,
    private val navigator: Navigator,
) : ViewModelFactory<SetCalorieGoalViewModel, SetCalorieGoalUiState, Nothing> {

    override fun create(savedState: SetCalorieGoalUiState?, parameters: Nothing?): SetCalorieGoalViewModel {
        TODO()
    }

}


@Module
interface SetCalorieGoalUiModule {

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(SetCalorieGoalViewModel::class)
    fun bindSetCalorieGoalViewModelFactory(factory: SetCalorieGoalViewModelFactory)
            : ViewModelFactory<ViewModel, Any, Any>

}
```

I can bind the `SetCalorieGoalViewModelFactory` to the `ViewModelFactory<SetCalorieGoalViewModel, Any, Any>` type without issue. What is the difference between these setups that makes one of them work and the other one not? I can't figure it out for the life of me. Big thanks in advance to anyone trying to solve this problem.

Comment: I think it's because the type in `interface Mapper<DTO, Entity>` is not defined. Meaning, it can be nullable as well. So make this `interface Mapper<DTO : Any, Entity : Any>` and see if it works

Comment: Good shout, thanks for your reply but unfortunately it didn't help, still the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, check out [kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#variance) on the generic variance topic as well as the related java topics (since dagger generates java code).

Generally the issue is that `Mapper<PersistedIntakeEntry, IntakeEntry>` and `Mapper<Any, Any>` are invariant, meaning that one is not subtype of the other. Basically this assignment `val mapper: Mapper<Any, Any> = PersistedIntakeEntryMapper()` will not compile and that's what dagger tells you. And that makes sense, since `Mapper<Any, Any>` must be able to map `Any` to `Any` and that's obviously not the case with `PersistedIntakeEntryMapper`  - it expects `PersistedIntakeEntry` and `IntakeEntry`.

Following the documentation above, it would be possible if your declaration had `out` modifier specified like `interface Mapper<out DTO, out Entity>`, but that will not work in your case, since you have your type arguments in `in` positions.

The interesting question is why it works with `ViewModelFactory`. It seems to be a bug in KAPT, it just omits generic type parameters in the generated code when it sees `Nothing`. It makes it bypass the compiler checks (but it does not make it safe to use at runtime!), since generics are mostly compile-time things (see *type erasure* in java).

Comment: Thanks for the thorough and thoughtful response, it made me understand a lot better. The interesting thing here is definitely why it works with the ViewModelFactory, as assigning `SetCalorieGoalViewModelFactory` to the type `ViewModelFactory<Any, Any, Any>` also results in a compiler error. So definitely reasonable to assume that it is due to a bug in kapt.
Since I'm doing an unchecked cast in my `MapperFactory`, the code is not runtime safe anyways, so the way I solved this problem is introducing a non generic `BaseMapper` interface to bind the specific mappers to.